# Testing Community "Passwordless Login" using the System.UserManagement Class

Tags: apex, community, authentication, gack

I am using the UserManagement class to register and login users with just their Email or Phone Number, which I have managed to get working very nicely...

I have now also built a small LWC to allow user to Register and Deregister an identifier. Which works nicely also...

My issue is how on earth do I test this?!

To check whether something has been Registered or is still Unregistered I am querying the `TwoFactorMethodsInfo` sObject to return back both the `HasUserVerifiedMobileNumber` and `HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress`, which allows me to update the UI to display different buttons, etc...

So in a test class when I call this method which is simply:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static TwoFactorMethodsInfo getVerifiedInfos(){
    // Confrim the User has a Verified Email Address and is able to login
    TwoFactorMethodsInfo verifiedInfos = [SELECT HasUserVerifiedMobileNumber, HasUserVerifiedEmailAddress
                                            FROM TwoFactorMethodsInfo
                                            WHERE UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

    return verifiedInfos;
}
```

It throws the following exception:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

So I decided to set SeeAllData to true (I had to fight the urges to the dark side after adding this), ran my test class again and then I got:

```
System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: We encountered an unexpected error. Contact Salesforce Customer Support. Error ID: 334613542-444174 (290339055)
```

So moving on further through my class, I thought I'd wait and deal with the headache later, surely I can run tests on the `System.UserManagement.initRegisterVerificationMethod()` or the `System.UserManagement.deregisterVerificationMethod`?

I removed the devil that is SeeAllData = true and continued on my journey to discovery. I added both methods into the Test Class, commenting out the beast above, surely this will work?

No... `initRegisterVerificationMethod` threw:

```
Failed to get network info.
```

With SeeAllData = true

```
Failed to get network info.
```

Errors... Again...

Let's try the `System.UserManagement.deregisterVerificationMethod`, who can guess the outcome?

Well no you were wrong... because even in a try/catch it still somehow threw an Exception that bypassed my try/catch:

```
System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1266895027-432990 (-1126684175) (-1126684175)
```

This is when I thought to myself: why am I being silly... surely I should create a user first using the `UserManagement.initSelfRegistration` method!

```
Failed to get network info.
```

Has ANYONE actually been able to test ANY of this? Or will I have to do something horrendous to actually cover any lines of code in this class?

Comment: Those error codes like `1266895027-432990 (-1126684175)` are [GACKs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html). Ideally they would be raised with Salesforce support so better error handling can be added to the internal code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the sad truth is that there is currently (as at v47.0) no support in Apex for testing those methods or the corresponding `TwoFactorMethodsInfo` API. I'm asking around for verification, but the docs don't provide any clarification or consideration for how to test them.

Since `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` isn't a good idea, I'd recommend wrapping the problematic functionality in an Apex class that can be mocked with the [Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm). The class and methods to be mocked can *not* be:

- static or future methods
- private methods
- properties (getters and setters)
- inner classes
- classes that only have private constructors

So you would make a public `UserManagementWrapper` class with it's own public `initRegisterVerificationMethod` and `deregisterVerificationMethod` methods that are direct pass throughs to the underlying `UserManagement` implementations.

Then, in your test methods you can use `MockUtil` to register your own mock implementation of `UserManagementWrapper` that returns whatever you need the method being tested to see.

Yes, it is a pain to have to perform these extra steps, but it should get you to a testable setup with minimal impact on the core code.

On the plus side, it will give you more control over what methods like `initRegisterVerificationMethod` return so you can simulate various return error messages.

---

A less ideal but maybe easier alternative to mocking is to use `Test.isRunningTest()` in your core Apex code to alter the code path when testing and avoid the problem methods. However, it does bring more testing mess into the main code flow.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I ended up raising a case with SF Premiere support, they're aware of the Stub API, but are doing some internal investigations... I'll let you know if this actually comes up with something :)

Comment: Salesforce have confirmed that none of these methods can be tested.... soooooo looks like I'll be working with the Stub API D:

Comment: The Sub API doesn't support the System.UserManagement class I end up getting this error: FATAL_ERROR System.TypeException: Test.createStub() can only be called with classes in the current namespace

Comment: @Tim That is why I suggested wrapping it in your own class that would meet the stubbing requirements.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I'm using the same class, not in Test context, but calling it's methods via a Public REST API class defined, to register users via a public website, and I'm getting the same error as OP: "System.NoAccessException: Failed to get network info." How can I overcome this issue?